# What are the towers of midnight

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the original guide that came out about 10-12 years ago, there is a map of Seanchan. There is a location in Seanchen called 'Towers of Midnight' that is not expanded on.

I think the book is referring to the White Tower and the Tower Mat went through to get to the Finn. However, has anyone seen an explanation of the actual towers of midnight from the old guide and if they tie into the book 'Towers of Midnight'?

Answer (score 4):

The title of the book is likely, at least in part, a reference to the Seanchan towers, which are mentioned a few times in the novel:

- One of Egwene's dreams involves 13 dark towers, falling over one by one. While this is also a pretty obvious references to the Forsaken, the actual towers she is seeing are likely a reference to those in Seanchan.
- There's a fragment of the Prophecy of Shadow at the end of the novel, which includes the line:

> Yea, and the Broken Wolf, the one whom Death has known, shall fall and be consumed by the Midnight Towers

- Slightly more meta, there are 13 Towers of Midnight and this is book 13 in the series :)

As far as what the Towers of Midnight actually are, the only information we have are those few brief mentions and some additional information that eventually made its way into the *Towers of Midnight* glossary, and some things mentioned by Jordan at one of the DragonCons. It's notable for being a key base of operations while Luthair Paendrag was conquering Seanchan, and for being where he imprisoned the Aes Sedai that invented the *a'dam*.

They are current unoccupied, until such time as the imperial family of Seanchan decides to

> return to the Towers of Midnight and "right that which is wrong."

---

That doesn't mean that the title is *only* referring to the Towers of Midnight in Seanchan; likely the title has multiple meanings. The other obvious reference is to the Black and White towers, and the Tower of Ghenji, since we see significant plot advancement on all three fronts.

Comment: Fun, I always assumed they referred to the Tower(s?) of Ghenji, and I somehow interpretated every reference to the Towers of Midnight referring to them!